# Sorting data between rows in R

Tags: r, sorting, if-statement, dataframe

Hypothetical data:

```
 a <- c(400,500,600,700,100,600,700,100)
 b <- c(2,2,1,2,2,1,2,1)
 c <- c('NA','R','NA','G','NA','R','NA','G')
 data <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Output:

```
    a b  c
1 400 2 NA
2 500 2  R
3 600 1 NA
4 700 2  G
5 100 2 NA
6 600 1  R
7 700 2 NA
8 100 1  G
```

You can easily subset if it is in the same row:

```
subset(data, b== '1' & c =='R')
```

Output:

```
    a b c
6 600 1 R
```

My question is how do I subset between rows?  For example, how do I find all values of c = 'R' when b = '2' on the above row?

```
    a b  c
2 500 1  R
6 600 1  R
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I find all values of `c = 'R'` when `b = '2'` **on the above row**?

How about

```
b2above <- which(data$b == 2) + 1L
cR <- which(data$c == "R")
id <- cR[cR %in% b2above]    ## or `id <- intersect(cR, b2above)`
data[id, ]

#    a b c
#2 500 2 R
#6 600 1 R
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too:

```
indices.b <- which(data$b == 2)
indices.c <- which(data$c == 'R')
if ((length(indices.b) > 0) && (length(indices.c) > 0)) { # if such rows exist
  indices <- which((indices.c - 1) %in% indices.b) # check if consecutive rows
  if(length(indices)>0) data[indices.c[indices],]  # if consecutive rows exist
}


#     a b c
# 2 500 2 R
# 6 600 1 R
```